# 422 Unprocessable Entity, When input is string instead of integer value, What is the reason behind it?

Tags: javascript, json, python-3.x, fastapi

HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
X-Powered-By: Express
date: Mon, 14 Jun 2021 10:20:50 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 117
content-type: application/json
access-control-allow-credentials: true
connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding

I've checked it in multiple components and same error shows.

Comment: Can you share your code so we can see what is happening?

Comment: I am sorry, I have not updated you. It was an issue from backend which our dev team has resolved.